# How to pass parameter top LOV query in SpagoBI

Tags: lov, spagobi

How I can pass a parameter to a LOV query in SPagoBI?

I am creating a LOV using query ... something like this:

```
select id, name
from table1
where parent_id = ${parent_id}
```

When I click on "Test before save" to evaluate query appears window with title "Profile attributes to fill" asking me to put value for parameter parent_id

Here is a text which appears on that page:

> The lov needs some profile attributes. 
>   Your personal profile doesn't contain all the necessary attributes. 
>   To proceed with the test assign a value to the missing profile attributes.

After filling with value and click on Test appears loading icon and stays stucked. I have checked logs. There is no error info in any of the following log files:  SpagoBI.log, catalina.out, SpagoBI_[1]_OperatorTrace.log, SpagoBIBirtReportEngine.log

I can see via   Express Profiler  that query is executed using valid passed parameter but why window stay stucked?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass parameter from report to the lovs.

The example given before is of the profile attributes which are passed on the basis of the user logged in.

see the below images for using profile attributes.

first create profile attribute you want to use.

[image]

Then you have to fill all the profile attribute corresponding to the user

[image]

Then create a lov using profile attribute you want i have created using venueId

see the below image

[image]

Now test the lov you will get the response see below image.

[image]

Use profile attributes when you want report that is specific to the user.

Answer (score 0):

you can use profile attribute in Dataset query like;

```sql
select id, name
from table1
where parent_id = '${parent_id}'
```

and use the created dataset in LOV.

Please note if query returns only 1 row analytical driver linked to document wont be visible, but will function as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap the attribute shortcode with single quotes in the query statement

like this

```
select id, name
from table1
where parent_id = '${parent_id}'
```

Comment: Here parent _id is profile attribute not the parameter passed from the report.
This profile attribute needs to be set then it will work for the profile from which user is logged in.